# Flex 4.5 MenuBar vertical separator (using updateDisplayList)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, menubar

So my client has a design for their flex skin navigation that looks like this:
[image]

I've created a custom MenuBar to make this happen. But it just doesn't seem to happen. It never renders any of the changes I made to the Graphics.
What am I doing wrong?

Here are the methods I've tried:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    this.graphics.clear();
    for (var i:int = 1; i < this.menuBarItems.length; i++) {
    var item:MenuBarItem = MenuBarItem(this.menuBarItems[i]);
        this.graphics.beginFill(textColor);
        this.graphics.drawRect(item.x + borderPadding, item.y, separatorSize, item.height);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```

or:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
    super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

    this.graphics.clear();
    for (var i:int = 1; i < this.menuBarItems.length; i++) {
    var item:MenuBarItem = MenuBarItem(this.menuBarItems[i]);
        item.graphics.beginFill(textColor);
        item.graphics.drawRect(borderPadding, 0, separatorSize, item.height);
        item.graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```

The css I have:

```
mx|MenuBar.navigation { 
backgroundSkin: Embed(source="assets/A2AD00-1x1.png");
itemOverSkin: Embed(source="assets/8B9300-1x1.png");
color: #ffffff;
borderPadding: 0;
separatorSize: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reluctantly switched to just using a 9-sliced image for it. For anyone else looking, here's what I did:

I made this image:
[image: 20 x 4]

(there's a one pixel white line on the right side)

And used this CSS:

```
mx|MenuBar.navigation { 
    backgroundSkin: Embed(source="assets/A2AD00-1x1.png");
    itemUpSkin: Embed(source="assets/nav_up.png",
        scaleGridTop="2",
        scaleGridLeft="2",
        scaleGridRight="18",
        scaleGridBottom="3");
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

It worked fine. Don't forget to add the assets to the build.xml for your theme:

```
<include-file name="assets/nav_up.png" path="${basedir}/src/assets/nav_up.png" />
<include-file name="assets/A2AD00-1x1.png" path="${basedir}/src/assets/A2AD00-1x1.png" />
```

Then I just threw out the class I had in my question, since it was useless.